# Can't read file correctly?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, filereader, filewriter

I have a game that I am making and I have a character selection screen in which on this screen you can add/del characters. Adding characters works fine but the deleting part is being weird or so I think.

Code Removed
ActionListener for delbutton

Which leads on to the delChar method of the program here.

```
public static void delChar(int charNum)
    {
        String input;
        try {
            ArrayList<String> oldFile = new ArrayList<String>();
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!input.startsWith(charNum + "*"))
                {
                    oldFile.add(input);
                }
            }
            br.close();
            FileWriter write = new FileWriter(file,false);
            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(write); 
            for (int i =0;i<oldFile.size();i++)
            {
                print.printf("%s" + "%n", oldFile.get(i));
            }
            write.close();

            print.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Then into the charSelect method here.

```
    public static void charSelect(){
        String[] stat = StatReader.getCharStats(charNum);
        if (StatWriter.getCharCount() <1)
        {
            name.setText("No Characters Created");
            classs.setText("");
            lv.setText("");
            ad.setText("");
            md.setText("");
            as.setText("");
            armor.setText("");
            mr.setText("");
            health.setText("");
            mana.setText("");
            energy.setText("");
            mReg.setText("");
            eReg.setText("");
            hReg.setText("");
        }
        try
        {
        name.setText(stat[0]);
        classs.setText(stat[1]);
        lv.setText(stat[2]);
        ad.setText(stat[3]);
        md.setText(stat[4]);
        as.setText(stat[5]);
        armor.setText(stat[6]);
        mr.setText(stat[7]);
        health.setText(stat[8]);
        mana.setText(stat[9]);
        energy.setText(stat[10]);
        mReg.setText(stat[11]);
        eReg.setText(stat[12]);
        hReg.setText(stat[13]);

//      System.out.println(charNum);
//      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stat));
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {

        }
        MainMenu.MMframe.repaint();
        MainMenu.MMframe.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Then after that I hoped that the screen would display "No characters" but it doesn't. Another thing I had discovered is that when I delete the char from the file it does indeed delete it but the program still thinks its there?

Here is the code involving the reading of the file.

```
public static String[] getCharStats(int CharNum)
    {
    try {
//      System.out.println(CharNum);
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
//              System.out.println(input);

                if (input.length() !=0)
                {
                    if (input.startsWith(CharNum + "*"))
                    {

                         getMultiStatLine(14);
                    }
                }
            }

            br.close();

//          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>Name:" + output[0]
//                  +"<br>Class:" + output[1]
//                  +"<br>Level:" + output[2]
//                  +"<br>Attack:" + output[3]
//                  +"<br>Magic:" + output[4]
//                  +"<br>Attack Speed:" + output[5]
//                  +"<br>Armor:" + output[6]       
//                  +"<br>Magic Resist:" + output[7]
//                  +"<br>Health:" + output[8]
//                  +"<br>Mana:" + output[9]
//                  +"<br>Energy:" + output[10]
//                  +"<br>Mana Regen:" + output[11]
//                  +"<br>Energy Regen:" + output[12]
//                  +"<br>Health Regen:" + output[13]);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return output;
    }
    public static String[] getMultiStatLine(int Places)
    {
        output = new String[Places];
        int[] bsSlots = new int[Places - 1];
        int bsPoints = 0;
                for (int i = 3; i < input.length();i++)
                {

                    if (input.charAt(i) == '/')
                    {
//                      System.out.println("found /");
                        bsPoints++;
                        bsSlots[bsPoints-1] = i;
//                      System.out.println(bsPoints);
//                      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bsSlots));
                    }
                    else if (bsPoints +1 == Places)
                    {
                        for (int c =0; c < Places; c++)
                        {
                            if (c == 0)
                            {
                                output[c] = input.substring(2,bsSlots[c]);
                            }
                            else if (c +1 == Places)
                            {
                                output[c] = input.substring(bsSlots[bsSlots.length - 1] + 1);
//                              System.out.println("c == " + Places);
                            }
                            else if (c > 0)
                            {
                                output[c] = input.substring(bsSlots[c-1] + 1,bsSlots[c]);
//                              System.out.println("c > 0");
                            }


//                          output[c] = input.substring();
                        }
                        i = input.length();
                        //md = input.substring(i + 1, input.length());
                        //ad = input.substring(2,i);

                    }

                }



        return output;

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Could you distill this into something more concise?   This a a lot of code to wade through.  Thanks

Comment: I feel the actionlistener is the only code i can really delete everything is is pretty essential to know for the program

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are deleting the character in the file, but you aren't telling the program to forget that character, did you try to update after delete?

Comment: How would I go about making the program forget about the character?

Comment: yes if you can be a bit more specific, ie, with code snipnets.